# match words containing at least one letter and at least one digit

Tags: regex, posix

I am new to regex but I have spent the last two days researching and I have also tried many of the similar queries in this and other sites.

I am trying to come up with an expression (POSIX ERE) that will find *whole words* that contain at least one letter and at least one digit. Specifically, I would like to capture all of these:

B/DIN/37/1
DU/32.Abb.31
P/NA.17
O/DIN/2017/8
22/N.Abb.2

I have tried many things and managed to crash my software a couple of times in the process, but still no go. One of my issues is I don't know how to phrase my string so it will find whole words that meet the criterion, not just a string within a word.

Thank you very much to anyone that can help me out!

Comment: extend your input with invalid words also. And specify your OS

Comment: I'm just going to leave this here for reference: https://regexr.com/ and https://regex101.com/ are excellent resources  when it comes to building/testing regular expressions.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming words are separated by whitespace. In that case, a word that has a digit and a letter can be separated into two regex expressions:

- 0 or more non-whitespace characters, followed by a letter, followed by 0 or more non-whitespace characters, followed by a digit, followed by 0 or more non-whitespace characters
- The above, but with digit and letter swapped.

The non-whitespace character matches make sure the entire word is captured.

Those translate into the following regexes:

- `\S*[A-Za-z]\S*[0-9]\S*`
- `\S*[0-9]\S*[A-Za-z]\S*`

Combining them yields this final expression:

`(\S*[A-Za-z]\S*[0-9]\S*|\S*[0-9]\S*[A-Za-z]\S*)`

Comment: And it works! Wonderful! Thank you so much, also for the clear explanation.